# Filtering django model with input parameters from html template

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model in the below format

model.py

```
raccntname = models.TextField(max_length=100)
raccntnum = models.TextField(max_length=100)
rLMV = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)
rSMV = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)
rcash = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)
requity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)
rLOMV = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)
rSOMV = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)
rhousereq = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)
rhouseexcess = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)
rregtexcess = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)
date = models.TextField(max_length=100)
entity = models.TextField(max_length=100)
```

I want to filter this model based on the selection from the below object lists

forms.py

```
class Datechoicefield(forms.Form):
date = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset= BNPPBMrgnDecmp.objects.values_list('date', flat=True).distinct(), initial='2/10/2020',
    empty_label = None,
)

class entitychoicefield(forms.Form):
entity = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset= BNPPBMrgnDecmp.objects.values_list('entity', flat=True).distinct(), initial='VNI3',
    empty_label = None,
)
```

html template

```
<form method='GET' action="{% url 'update' %}">
     {{ date_list }}
     {{ entity_list }}
     <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

The selections from the object list is passed into the view via the below

view.py

```
def myview(request):
    date_list = Datechoicefield()
    entity_list = entitychoicefield()
    if request.GET.get('date'):
    selected_date = request.GET.get('date')
    obj = BNPPBMrgnDecmp.objects.filter(date=selected_date)
        if request.GET.get('entity'):
            selected_entity = request.GET.get('entity')
            obj = BNPPBMrgnDecmp.objects.filter(raccntname=selected_entity)
    else:
    obj = BNPPBMrgnDecmp.objects.filter(date='2/10/2020', entity='VNI3')
```

The above model should filter by date and by entity. However, when the objects from the form are selected from the html template, the results are only filtered by date and gives the data for ALL entities(where only one is selected). Also, the else statement works to filter on the specified date/entity. Is there something wrong with my if statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently each filter you apply is for all the `BNPPBMrgnDecmp` objects.  Ie. each `obj = BNPPBMrgnDecmp.objects.filter()` is a whole new assignment.

Consider something like the following:

```
filtered = BNPPBMrgnDecmp.objects.all()

if request.GET.get('date'):
    selected_date = request.GET.get('date')
    # Set to the existing filtered variable
    filtered = filtered.filter(date=selected_date)

if request.GET.get('entity'):
    selected_entity = request.GET.get('entity')
    # If there was a 'date' in request.GET, the filter will 
    # already be applied to the queryset now in the filtered variable
    filtered = filtered.filter(raccntname=selected_entity)
```

Comment: This was helpful  - my real issue was how my form's object was mapped according to my view.